# Find ports used by a specific process on macOS

Tags: macos, network, command-line

There are dozens of answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375351/how-to-find-which-process-has-opened-the-port-on-macos) and [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340165/find-out-what-is-running-on-my-port-80-on-a-mac-osx) on how to find what process is using a specific port, but so far I haven't found a better way to find what ports are being used by a process other than

```sh
lsof -i -P | grep <PID>
```

which is *extremely slow* (> 5s on my 2021 MacBook Pro).

It seems as though

```sh
lsof -p <PID> -i -P
```

should filter by process, but it doesn't; the `-i -P` options seem to override the `-p` filter.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `lsof` options work is somewhat counterintuitive. Per the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) (Linux version, but as of macOS 12.2 Monterey and `lsof` 4.91, the Mac version seems to be identical):

> Normally list options that are specifically stated are ORed —
> i.e., specifying the **-i** option without an address and the **-u**foo
> option produces a listing of all network files OR files belonging
> to processes owned by user “foo”.
>
> [...]
>
> The **-a** option may be used to AND the selections.  For example,
> specifying **-a**, **-U**, and **-u**foo produces a listing of only UNIX
> socket files that belong to processes owned by user “foo”.

In order to apply *both* the `-i` filter and the `-p` filter, it's therefore necessary to also specify `-a`:

```
$ lsof -i -P -a -p 46774                                                                                   COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    46774 david   10u  IPv4 0x4e2119e3c90b016b      0t0  TCP *:63597 (LISTEN)
ruby    46774 david   11u  IPv4 0x4e2119e3c90bcbfb      0t0  TCP localhost:63597->localhost:63599 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    46774 david   14u  IPv4 0x4e2119e3c90c4bfb      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Note that where the `-a` is placed is not important. Per the man page:

> Caution: the **-a** option causes all list selection options to be
> ANDed; it can't be used to cause ANDing of selected pairs of
> selection options by placing it between them, even though its
> placement there is acceptable.  Wherever **-a** is placed, it causes
> the ANDing of all selection options.

So the following are all equivalent.

```sh
lsof -i -P -a -p 46774 
lsof -a -p 46774 -i -P
lsof -a -i -p 46774 -P
lsof -P -p 46774 -i -a
```